# Fedora 35 isn't loading

Tags: fedora, boot

I've recently installed Fedora 35 on my laptop (next to my windows installation) and has been using it for couple of weeks (nothing fancy, some programming just to get to know linux). Today I've encountered a problem on system loading. I got:

```
error: ../../grub-core/kern/dl.c:265:invalid arch-independent ELF magic.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I can't event choose which OS I want to load (fedora/windows).

As I've mentioned, these are my first steps in this system so I'm aware that my problem is not well described - I'll try to update my question with some more insights. I'd use any help to diagnose problem and find solution.

My hardware information:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Machine manufacturer/type-model | Lenovo/20KGS61900 |
| BIOS | N23ET78W (1.53 lenovo) |
| Processor | Intel Core i7-8550U |
| Memory origin/type/size (2x) | SMBIOS/LPDDR3/8GB |
| SSD | Samsung MZVLB256HAHQ-000L7 |

Output of ***blkid*** command (when booted from USB):

```
/dev/sda1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2021-10-26-06-03-59-00" LABEL="Fedora-WS-Live-35-1-2" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="14fc2edf" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="14fc2edf-01"
/dev/loop1: LABEL="Anaconda" UUID="8e88a3a2-d9af-4034-9ad9-594e1a0d514b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/live-base: LABEL="Anaconda" UUID="8e88a3a2-d9af-4034-9ad9-594e1a0d514b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="7c912417-75f8-4be5-a6c4-d96ba1a1f94b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="de346181-05"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="System" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="9A90C24390C2259B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="de346181-01"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="Recovery" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="9CDAC2FDDAC2D326" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="de346181-04"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: LABEL="Windows" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="BCA2C2D0A2C28E78" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="de346181-02"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/mapper/live-rw: LABEL="Anaconda" UUID="8e88a3a2-d9af-4034-9ad9-594e1a0d514b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="ANACONDA" LABEL="ANACONDA" UUID="A4EE-315B" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="14fc2edf-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="6632cc02-5ada-3832-a9be-9043258bdfc9" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" LABEL="ANACONDA" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTUUID="14fc2edf-03"
/dev/zram0: LABEL="zram0" UUID="d8fec898-bdba-41db-a4e9-faf4d1070596" TYPE="swap"
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add information about your hardware. Also, did you see https://askubuntu.com/questions/72003/how-do-i-resolve-a-grub-invalid-arch-independent-elf-magic-error? Looks promising. It's Ubuntu but still.

Comment: Looks like a grub update has failed. Please boot from a recovery and reinstall the package. Your disk drive might also be failing.

Comment: Hi @Edward, thanks for interest of problem that I've encountered. I've editem my question. Also, I've tried to follow instructions from your link, but couldn't execute `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot ` - I've got "mount point does not exist" error.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've run full diagnostics using Lenovo BIOS utilities and everything seems to be ok. By "boot from recovery" you mean for example usb stick? If so, I tried that, but after performing `sudo dnf install grub2` I gets `Package grub2-pc-1:2.06-6.fc35.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
` and nothing changes on booting system.

Comment: try `sudo dnf reinstall grub2-pc`

Comment: Also, check the Fedora guide on grub2 at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2 and follow the steps set out there.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I tried what you'd suggested meaning I've opened fedora system with usb stick, then I've executed `sudo dnf reinstall grub2-pc`. Command finished with success, but when I've put out usb stick and tried to launch fedora from hard drive, my initial error occured again. I also tried to follow guide about grub2 but I can't "mount the root partition" as command `chroot /mnt/sysimage` returns *"failed to run command '/bin/bash' :No such file or directory'"*. I see some solutions to that last error but I don't understand how can i use any of them in my case.